# change start position of horizontal scrollbar without jquery

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

In Jquery I'm aware you can move the scrollbars' starting location. Is this possible with pure javascript? To clarify, when the user loads the page I simply want the horizontal scrollbar to start scrolled all the way to the right, instead of starting at the left. If there are cross-browser issues, I'm particularly concerned with this working in Chrome.

Comment: simply setting elm.scrollLeft=9e9; will push a horizontal scroll all the way to the right, no measuring needed.

Comment: `document.getElementById('randomID').element.scrollLeft=9e9` isn't working for me?

Comment: take off the extra ".element" and try it

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you officially answer this question so I can accept? This is the best, simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

document.body.scrollLeft = ( divRef.scrollWidth - divRef.offsetWidth ) / 2 ;

**NOTE**:

This can give odd results with IE8 and earlier.

Comment: I'm a newbie. Does this only work on the body element? where do i give this an element ID? I tried this `document.getElementById('randomId').scrollLeft = ( divRef.scrollWidth - divRef.offsetWidth ) / 2 ;` with no success

Comment: Actually, this method should work just fine with getElementById; most of the documentation on scrollLeft is written for an object.  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example with a div, you can easily adjust this to your body tag, or another div, please see the demo.

```
var a = document.getElementById('body');
console.log(a.clientWidth)
function moveWin(a) {
    window.scrollTo(a.clientWidth,0);                                     

}
moveWin(a)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg3npgmn/)

SIDENOTE:

To select the body, simply use

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```